# How to check if a file is a valid image?

Tags: go, mime

I am building a web application.

On one of the pages there is an upload form, where user can upload a file. After the upload is done, I want to check on the server if the uploaded file is an image.

Is it possible to check this beyond simple file extension checking (i.e. not assuming that a `*.png` filename is actually a PNG image)?

For example, if I edit a JPEG image adding/editing a byte in a random place to make an invalid JPEG file, I want to detect that it is not a JPEG image anymore. I used to do such type of thing via PHP some time ago, using a GD library.

I would like to know if it is possible to do with Go?

Comment: What you want is not always possible. Inserting a random character into the middle of an image file will corrupt the image but it will usually not stop being an image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is usually done is checking if the file has the right [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) for the image file format you want. While this test is not super accurate, it is usually good enough. You can use code like this:

```
package foo

import "strings"

// image formats and magic numbers
var magicTable = map[string]string{
    "\xff\xd8\xff":      "image/jpeg",
    "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n": "image/png",
    "GIF87a":            "image/gif",
    "GIF89a":            "image/gif",
}

// mimeFromIncipit returns the mime type of an image file from its first few
// bytes or the empty string if the file does not look like a known file type
func mimeFromIncipit(incipit []byte) string {
    incipitStr := []byte(incipit)
    for magic, mime := range magicTable {
        if strings.HasPrefix(incipitStr, magic) {
            return mime
        }
    }

    return ""
}
```

Comment: If for some reason checking the header isn't sufficient you could load all the relevent image packages (`image/png`, `image/gif`, `image/jpeg`, `golang.org/x/image/bmp`, etc) and use `image.DecodeConfig` or [`image.Decode`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode) and check for errors. Beware of malicious data targeting bugs in the decoders though.

Comment: @DaveC As said in my own comment further above, decoding the image is not solving the problem as altering random bytes in the middle of the image does not in general cause the image file to be recognized as “corrupted.”

Comment: indeed! Without a secure hash of the original you cannot detect benign modifications. However, *if desired* (as your answer says, just the header is usually good enough) you can check that the full data represents a valid image (assuming the relevant image decoding reports errors for bad/invalid input rather than just returning a corrupt image with no error; e.g. simple image formats that just include the raw pixel data will decode fine as long as the correct number of bytes are present whereas I'd hope something like a JPEG decoder is more picky about it's compressed input).

Answer (score 34):

[DetectContentType](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DetectContentType) is way better than a manual magic number checking. The use is simple:

```
clientFile, _, _ := r.FormFile("img") // or get your file from a file system
defer clientFile.Close()
buff := make([]byte, 512) // docs tell that it take only first 512 bytes into consideration
if _, err = clientFile.Read(buff); err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err) // do something with that error
     return
}

fmt.Println(http.DetectContentType(buff)) // do something based on your detection.
```

Using this method you need to know that you still are not guaranteed to have a correct file. So I would recommend to do some image manipulation with that file (like resize it to make sure this is really an image).

Comment: can you please explain further. So we resize and then what else should we do?

Answer (score 22):

The http package can do this for you:

> ```
> func DetectContentType(data []byte) string
> ```
>
> DetectContentType implements the algorithm described at
>   http://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/ to determine the Content-Type of the
>   given data. It considers at most the first 512 bytes of data.
>   DetectContentType always returns a valid MIME type: if it cannot
>   determine a more specific one, it returns "application/octet-stream".

Code: https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go