# How do I detect file type of input that's piped into a Go program that expects either images or gifs?

Tags: go, pipe, command-line-interface, stdin

I have a cli tool that accepts input in the form of file paths or urls (which can be gifs or images). Currently, I'm differentiating btw the two by their extensions (`.gif`, `.jpg` etc at the end of the paths), but I'm stumped on how to do that if the input is piped from a different process in the command line.

For instance, how will `myGoProgram` know the piped input is a `.png` or a `.gif` in the example below?

```bash
cat image.png | ./myGoProgram -
```

Here's how I'm decoding piped stdin for an image using the `image` go module right now:

```golang
decodedImg, _, err := image.Decode(os.Stdin)
```

...And the same with a decoding a gif through the `image/gif` go module:

```golang
decodedGif, err = gif.DecodeAll(os.Stdin)
```

But I don't understand how I'm supposed to know if it's a gif or an image from `os.Stdin`

Comment: You can use the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959386/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-valid-image (read the first 512 bytes from stdin, then use http.DetectContentType, and you're done).

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be working perfectly for now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to work out a solution with the help of the question referred by [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)

Overall logic for how I differentiated btw images, gifs and invalid inputs:

```golang
// imports:
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// -----
// logic:
var pipedInputTypes = []string{
    "image/png",
    "image/jpeg",
}
var inputIsGif bool

pipedInputBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to read piped input: %v", err)
}

fileType := http.DetectContentType(pipedInputBytes)
invalidInput := true

if fileType == "image/gif" {
    inputIsGif = true
    invalidInput = false
} else {
    for _, inputType := range pipedInputTypes {
        if fileType == inputType {
            invalidInput = false
            break
        }
    }
}

if invalidInput {
    log.Fatalf("Cannot read piped input of type \"%v\"", fileType)
}

if inputIsGif {
    // Gif program logic with pipedInputBytes
} else {
    // Image program logic with pipedInputBytes
}
```